# how to change name of hidden field which generate with checkboxfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view like bellow

```
@model IEnumerable<elearnerhub.Common.Entities.ViewModel.elearnerhub.vm_eLearning_Master_QuestionSet_AnswerOptions>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => item.AnswerShownOrder,item.AnswerShownOrder.ToString(), new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.AnswerOptionText, new { @class = "form-control", @id=item.PK_MasterQuestion_AnswerOptionID, Name = "AnswerOptionText" })


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => item.CorrectAnswer, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "chk"+item.PK_MasterQuestion_AnswerOptionID, @Name = "CorrectAnswer" })

            </div>
        </div>
    }

public PartialViewResult _QuestionAnswerOptions(Int64 noofoptions)
    {

        List<vm_eLearning_Master_QuestionSet_AnswerOptions> _vm_eLearning_Master_QuestionSet_AnswerOptions = new List<vm_eLearning_Master_QuestionSet_AnswerOptions>();


        for(int i = 0; i <= noofoptions-1; i++)
        {
            var obj = new vm_eLearning_Master_QuestionSet_AnswerOptions
            {
                PK_MasterQuestion_AnswerOptionID= i + 1,
                AnswerShownOrder=i+1,
                AnswerOptionText="",
                CorrectAnswer=false


            };
            _vm_eLearning_Master_QuestionSet_AnswerOptions.Add(obj);
        }

        return PartialView("_QuestionSet_AnswerOptions");
    }
```

and the hidden field generate with checkbox with different name .please see the screen shot of inspect element

[image]

How to set the name of the hidden field same as check box?

Comment: Is your code generates on page load.? or on any other action.?

Comment: is it created automatically? or some code is doing that?

Comment: please see I update my question with action which return the partial view

Comment: Do not use a `foreach` loop - your code will never bind to your model, you will never get any validation etc - refer [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Comment: @weBer its generate a dropdown's change event and jquery load the partial.

Comment: what i asked is those hidden fields are created automatically? or some code line doing that?

Comment: And never under any circumstances, attempt to change the `name` attribute when using `HtmlHelper` methods

Comment: You should not change name. If you want to have your own name, just don't use html helpers (Html.CheckboxFor).

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this simple snippet as your solution -**

Here the `.dropDownClass` should be the class you used for your **`dropdown`**

```js
$('body').on('change', '.dropDownClass', function() {
  var naMe = $('#chk1').attr('name')
  $('#chk1').parent().find('input[type="hidden"]').attr('name', naMe)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="" id="" class="dropDownClass">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <input id="chk1" class="form-control" name="CorrectAnswer" data-value="true" value="true" type="checkbox">
  <input name="item.CorrectAnswer" value="false" type="hidden">
</div>
```

I hope this helps you, if there is anything more please do ask.

Comment: thanks for your code @weBer but I don't want extra code for fixing ,Is the no way to fix this with MVC please see my post I update my code there

Comment: If it's like that then you should not have put `jQuery` tag. Sorry, i can only help you with jQuery.

Comment: Is there any MVC option where we can control the hidden field generate with checkboxfor?

Comment: Am not used to do the project with **MVC** so can't help you on that. but this is a simple jQuery solution you can use.